# Kivy - Calling a pulsing method from one class to another

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following classes in my kivy app, and i would like to call the `blink` method in my `mainApp` class. The `start pulsing` and `blink` methods enable the `MainWindow` background to pulse. However it's not working inside the `MainWindow` class and i need to call it in my `mainApp` class. Commented out (`build` method in `mainApp`) is what i tried, which results to the error  `Exception: Invalid instance in App.root`. My python file:

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ColorProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from plyer import filechooser


data = ""
class MainWindow(Screen):

    def analyze_data(self):
        global data
        data = self.ids.user_input.text
        data = analyze(data)


    animated_color = ColorProperty()  
    pulse_interval = 4  

    def blink(self):
        x = Clock.schedule_once(self.start_pulsing, 5)
        return x

    
    def start_pulsing(self, *args):
        d = self.pulse_interval / 2
        anim = Animation(animated_color=(69/255, 114/255, 147/255, 1), duration=d) + Animation(animated_color=(1, 1, 1, 1), duration=d)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(self)


class OutputScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.output_label.text = data

class mainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


    def choose_file(self):
        try:
            filechooser.open_file(on_selection = self.handle_selection)
        except:
            pass


    def handle_selection(self,selection):
        global path
        selection_ls = selection[0]
        path = selection_ls
        #print(path)


    def change_screen(self,screen):
        screemanager = self.root.ids['screenmanager']
        screemanager.current = screen


    def change(self):
        self.change_screen('output')

    def back(self):
        self.change_screen('main')
'''
    def build(self):
        x = MainWindow().blink()
        return x'''
```

and my kv file:

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
GridLayout:
    cols:1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screenmanager
        MainWindow:
            id: main
            name: 'main'
        OutputScreen:
            id: output
            name: 'output'

<MainWindow>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'

        MDBottomNavigation:
            panel_color: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name:'analytics'
                text:'analytics'
                icon:'account-circle'

                FloatLayout:
                    size: root.width, root.height
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: root.animated_color
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.pos
                            size:self.size
           
                    TextInput:
                        multiline:True
                        id: user_input1
                        pos_hint:{"x" : 0.05, "top" : 0.9}
                        size_hint: 0.9, 0.37
                    Label:
                        markup: True
                        id:input_label
                        pos_hint:{"x" : 0, "top":1}
                        size_hint: 1 ,0.08
                        font_size : 32
                        bold: True
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("01121c")
                            Rectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos
                    Button:
                        pos_hint:{"top" : 0.51, "x" : 0.05}
                        size_hint: (None,None)
                        width : 150
                        height : 40
                        font_size : 23
                        text:'Submit'
                        on_press: root.analyze_data()
                        on_release: app.change()
                    Button:
                        pos_hint:{"top":0.42, "x":0.05}
                        size_hint: (None,None)
                        width : 150
                        height : 40
                        font_size : 23
                        text:'Upload'
                        on_release:app.choose_file()
                    Button:
                        id:'info_button'
                        pos_hint:{"top":0.47, "x":0.8}
                        size_hint: (None,None)
                        width : 50
                        height : 22
                        font_size : 23
                        text:'i'
                        on_release:root.analytics_info()

<OutputScreen>:
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            MDIconButton:
                icon:'arrow-left'
                pos_hint:{'top':1,'left':1}
                size_hint: 0.1,0.1
                user_font_size : '64sp'
                on_release: app.back()
            Label:
                id: output_label
                multiline:True
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                color: 0,0,0,1
                padding_x: 15
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build()` method of an `App` should return a `Widget` that will become the root of the `App`. But your `build()` method returns a `ClockEvent` (the return from `Clock.schedule_once()`). Try changing your `build()` method to:

```
def build(self):
    x = MainWindow()
    x.blink()
    return x
```

Since you do not call `Builder.load_file()`, I assume that your `kv` file is named `main.kv`, and therefore will get loaded automatically. If that is true, then you do not need a `build()` method at all. Instead add an `on_start()` method to your `mainApp` class, like this:

```
def on_start(self):
    self.root.ids.main.blink()
```